# Developing a VR game but it is so much laggy

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am developing an Android game which is based on VR, In game player is free to move around an amusement park which will be filled with stuff like stalls, toys, Ferris wheels, rails and other carnival rides. Now if I put a big mesh like rails and Ferris wheels which have around 400k+ polycount each and when I run it on my smartphone (galaxy s7 edge) I face hitching and lagg viewing the scean in VR. I also reduced polygons from some objects, fixed texture resolution but still no way near getting it close to run at 50-60fps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the only expensive thing is the number of polys in your scene, you're going to need to experiment around to determine just how heavy your scene can be before unacceptable lag occurs. Try scaling back the number of objects you have, deploy it to your phone, and check the framerate. Increase the objects until you've reached a point where it starts getting laggy - there, you have your limit. Work within it. You may need to get creative on how to optimize your scene without seriously reducing visual fidelity, but hey - that's mobile development.

Comment: @Serlite I have a rail track which i want to show in my game but because of alot of polygons my device laggs running it. How can achieve smooth ganeplay while keeping things I want?

Comment: Is this upvoted because of _"Oh, cool, VR!"_? The question _"How can I optimize my game"_ is way too broad.

Comment: @Serlite one piece of rail consist of 1k polys.. i made a full roller coaster track with that piece and now polys are something like 400k and is causing lagg. i cant decrease the lenght of rail, in this case what can i do

Comment: @Ebadkhan Uuuhm...how high-poly does a rail actually have to be? Are you sure you can't reduce the poly count and apply normal maps to it instead, if you need it to appear smoother? That's a lot of polys for something which the user (probably) won't be sticking their face into.

Comment: @Serlite I have attached the pictures of my rail which is made on blender with single piece of rail (picture! attached 1k polygons) after all the pieces are joined it made 1 big mesh of rail as you can see which is of 400k polys, and its causing hitching on mobile, if i reduce the length of this rail to some extent the fps gets better but i cant decrease the length of my rail, what can i do in this case i'd be really grateful to you.

Comment: @Ebadkhan Wait - did you combine all your meshes in Blender into a single mesh? You shouldn't do that - many of Unity's optimizations work better with many small objects, rather than a single gargantuan mesh. Give them the same material, then make sure you've set all the rail segments to Static. Here's some reading on how Unity does draw call batching to save rendering time: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html

Comment: @Ebadkhan Something else to consider: level of detail model variants (which will be possible once you break up your rail). Supply lighter models to be displayed at longer distances, since at sufficient distance the details of a rail really aren't discernible: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LevelOfDetail.html

Comment: @Serlite yes i made it on blender using paths and curves it is easy to make curvy rail using path, if i am using single object than i have to worry about translating/scaling/rotating for each rail piece to make it look like curvy, or is there a better approach to make rail which is convenient and reliable as far as performance is concerned.

Comment: @Ebadkhan A common approach with roads/rails and similar objects is to create numerous modular pieces, which can be joined together in any manner as required in the game. (So, you might have a straight piece, a piece curved upward, a corkscrewing piece, etc.) You will have to manually position them, yeah - but if you made the pieces right, it'll be as simple as assembling Lego to create complex forms that would have otherwise required extra modeling and tweaking. This makes future adjustment easier (all within Unity, no Blender), and lets you make many different tracks from the same pieces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are building it for Oculus platforms, here are some performance requirements:

1. 60 frames per second
2. 50-100 drawcalls per frame
3. 50k – 100k polygons per frame
4. 1 ~ 3 ms spent in script execution (Unity Update())

To optimize your game:

1. Use [Lightmaps](https://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/Manual/Lightmapping.html)/baked lights instead of run-time/dynamic lighting.
2. Mark stationary objects as static to use static/dynamic [batching](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html). This will reduce drawcalls.
3. Use [Oculusion culling](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html) to save rendering power. This will reduce tricount and drawcalls.
4. Use fewer materials in your objects by putting separate textures into a larger texture atlas.
5. Use Compressed textures to decrease the size of your textures.
6. Use Generate MipMaps option on importing textures to save GPU power.

[Read More](https://developer3.oculus.com/blog/squeezing-performance-out-of-your-unity-gear-vr-game/) about optimization for VR.

[Read More](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OptimizingGraphicsPerformance.html) about Graphic Optimization in Unity

Hope this helps

Comment: VEry useful for optimizing VR games

Comment: @Umair M i have attached the picture of my rail, see if the user is sitting on a roller coaster and coaster moves to higher point on rail than rest of the rail will be visible in the view and amount of poly is too much and will cause lag as it is exceeding the limit of 50-100k per frame constraint, in this situation what am i supposed to do, i'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Ebadkhan You will surely exceed rendered poly-count limit when player looks at entire scene from top. i assume that player is allowed to move freely in the scene. That's fine. Use above techniques to optimize your game. But if in the ride part, If movement is not controlled by user It would be better to render a 360 view into a video and use it on a sphere which will only be 5k polygons at max. As the ride is just a simulation where user can only look around. This is just merely a suggestion. Mobile devices are not ready for heavy scenes.

Comment: How does this compare to mobile, say iOS?

Comment: most of the stuff here is useful for iOS too. you can use quality settings to optimize your app for low-end devices, iPhone 4 for example. Read through [this guide](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-performance.html) for more ios specific optimization

Answer (score 1):

The main problem (not only in VR) are dynamic lighting.
Try to disable all your lights and if you really need some shadows, bake it.

Here is a [Quick tutorial](https://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/Manual/Lightmapping.html) about lightmapping.